# onTap() of InkWell not triggering

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Also tried onPressed() IconButton , not printing . Tried IgnorePointer as well , no change , interesting thing is onLongPress() is working .is it because inside a container .This green button am talking about.

[image]

```
                              Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  width:50,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: myGreen, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.send,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    onTap:(){
                                      print("sdsdsd");
                                      //sendChatToFirestore();
                                    },
                                    onLongPress: (){
                                      print("long press");
                                    },

                                  ),
                                )
```

Comment: Just use `Icon` instead of `IconButton` or remove `InkWell`.

Comment: You got two onPressed and onTap methode which are basically the same thing triggered at same time. Remove one of them and it will work

Comment: @Blasanka initially it was Icon , it was not working so tried Iconbutton .

Comment: @delmin well that are two different properties , but yes I tried removing OnLongPress to be sure , still not working .

Comment: Two different properties triggered at the same gesture... remove onTap or onPressed. You can’t have both in one widget!!!

Comment: @delmin yes tried removing , not working , edited code in above question as well .

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Instead of creating mess with multiple widget you can use out of the box FAB which do the same thing

```
FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("sdsdsd");
          //sendChatToFirestore();
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.send,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
```

Or if you want a more control over the button use simple FlatButton

```
FlatButton(               //change to RaisedButton to be raised
          onPressed: () {
            print("sdsdsd");
            //sendChatToFirestore();
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            print("long press");
          },
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.send,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
```

There is no need to reinvent the wheel for such simple widget

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: will that give the ripple effect as well ? and also this does not answer the question , why onTap() is not triggered , is tat a bug with the dart version ?

Comment: yes... it gives you effect like normal button has. try it and let me know

Comment: it isn't bug.. it is just an improper use of the widget from your side with previous code you had in your question

Comment: and BTW I have tested your updated code and onTap is triggered properly

Answer (score 0):

Ink well renders a ripple animation when inside a `Material` widget. You can set most of the customizations you would normally give to a `Container` here as well. Wrap a material widget around your inkwell and you are done.

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width:50,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: myGreen, shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: Material(child:                  // <- This is the magic widget
        InkWell(
          child: Icon(
          Icons.send,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
     ),
      onTap:(){
          print("sdsdsd");
          //sendChatToFirestore();
      },
      onLongPress: (){
          print("long press");
      },
   ),
)
```

But as mentioned in other answers and comments, probably going for a pre-built widget makes more sense in this case. Unless of course, you need to set up your own gesture detection system for the widget